# I am using fs.createReadStream and pipe to copy file. The source file has been deleted, the file stream will exist?

Tags: node.js

I copy the files in this way, in the process of copying files deleted the source files, but also can copy success. I want to know why you will be successful? This file has been deleted, the file stream will exist?

```
var fs=require('fs');
var rOption={
    flags:"r",
    encoding:null,
    mode:0666
}

var wOption = {
    flags: 'a',
    encoding: null,
    mode: 0666
}

var fileReadStream=fs.createReadStream('file1.rar',rOption);
var fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('file2.rar',wOption);

fileReadStream.on('data',function(data){
    fileWriteStream.write(data);
});

fileReadStream.on('error',function(err){
    console.log(err)
});

fileReadStream.on('end',function(){
    console.log("readStream end");
    fileWriteStream.end();
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with how it currently works? Please ask a direct question so it's clear how you want it to work.

Comment: When the file1.rar was copying to file2.rar, i deleted file1.rar. 'file2.rar' was be created. I want to know where the stream from, because the file1.rar was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var fs=require('fs');
var rOption={
    flags:"r",
    encoding:null,
    mode:0666
}

var wOption = {
    flags: 'a',
    encoding: null,
    mode: 0666
}

var fileReadStream=fs.createReadStream('file1.rar',rOption);
var fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('file2.rar',wOption);

fileReadStream.on('end', function() {
  fs.unlink('file1.rar', function(){});
});

fileReadStream.pipe(fileWriteStream);
```

Comment: My mean is when it running, why i can delete the file1.rar from file system not by code. And when i deleted the file, the copy process is finished, the local file is deleted, where is the stream from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Unix-like OS (like Linux or OS X), this is expected behaviour: when you delete a file, you are "merely" removing its directory entry.

When a process (your Node app) has an open reference (the stream) to such a file, the actual file contents remain available to that process. Only when the reference is closed will the contents become "deleted" (the disk space is marked as being available).

This method is also used to create temporary files that will automatically be deleted once the process stops: a file is created and opened, its directory entry is deleted, but as long as the file remains open it can be read and/or written. When the file is closed (which also happens when the process exits), the disk space is marked as available again.

I don't know if, and how, this would work on Windows.

Comment: @user5010266 in that case, it seems that the same principle would apply to Windows as well.

Comment: Not like that , under the Windows file is not locked.I can delete it any way.But the stream seems to be existed

Comment: @user5010266 the file isn't locked on Unix either, that's why you can delete it and still read from it :-) But like I said, I'm not familiar with Windows, so I don't know when it will or won't lock files. On Unix, files are (almost?) never locked.

Comment: I think this stream does not depend on the file storage path.I am not sure.